# COGNOS 10.2: Auto-Submit only works by running the report out of report studio

Tags: reporting, cognos, cognos-10, cognos-bi, report-studio

Hello i am facing following problem.

I am have an report with a prompt page that contains three dates prompts. For each of these prompts I have added a JavaScript-Element so that a specific value is always selected. For this i have used following code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var fW = (typeof getFormWarpRequest == "function" ? getFormWarpRequest(): document.forms["formWarpRequest"]);
if(fW)
{
if(fW._oLstChoices1.length >= 1)
{
fW._oLstChoices1.selectedIndex = 18;
}
}
</script>
```

At the end i have a seperate list-prompt filled with static values, that runs the report automatically:

```
<script>
    var form = getFormWarpRequest();
    var list = form._oLstChoicesdummy;
    list.selectedIndex = 0;
    canSubmitPrompt();
    setTimeout('oCVRS.promptAction(\'finish\')', 0); 

</script>
```

When I open the report in Report Studio and click on "RUN", the report is executed automatically. But if I run the report outside of Report Studio, the prompt mask appears again and I have to click on "Finish/Run".

Has anyone faced silimiar problems and knows how to solve it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you hit F12 to open the console, you'll probably see a javascript error

Answer (score 2):

If anyone else should face the same problem you can use the following code that will autosubmit the prompt page:

```
    <script type="text/javascript"> 

//get the form request 
var fW = (typeof getFormWarpRequest == "function" ? getFormWarpRequest() : document.forms["formWarpRequest"]); 

if (fW) 
{ 
  // if the report is running from reportStudio or the Portal objects are different 
  if (fW.elements["cv.id"].value == "RS") 
  { 
     setTimeout('oCVRS.promptAction(\'next\')', 1000); 
  }else{ 
    setTimeout('oCV_NS_.promptAction(\'next\')', 1000); 
  } 
} 
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for returning with an answer. Could you please add the Cognos version as different code is required for different versions